# What counts as sufficient prior research when asking a question?

Tags: discussion, faq

On Martial Arts Stack Exchange, people asking questions are expected to demonstrate that they've put a certain amount of effort into answering the question themselves.

**What exactly counts as sufficient effort?**

---

<sup><sub>[Shamelessly stolen from physics.se…](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5778/11380)</sub></sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What research do I need to do before asking a question?

> Before asking a question, do anything else you can think of that might
>   get you the answer.

- Looking up the question in [Google](http://www.google.com) or [another search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/) as a  bare minimum… Note that [LMGTFY links are now banned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15650/227017) but that should not preclude the poster from googling the question themselves.
- Also search a few combinations of key words, and again look at the top few results.

## OK, I didn't find the answer. Now what?

- If your prior research didn't give the answer you were looking for,
  tell us what you checked.